# Bash scripting wanting to find a size of a directory and if size is greater than x then do a task

Tags: linux, bash

I have put the following together with a couple of other articles but it does not seem to be working. What I am trying to do eventually do is for it to check the directory size and then if the directory has new content above a certain total size it will then let me know.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=private/videos/tv
minimumsize=2
actualsize=$(du -m "$file" | cut -f 1)
if [ $actualsize -ge $minimumsize ]; then
        echo "nothing here to see"
else
        echo "time to sync"
fi 

this is the output:
./sync.sh: line 5: [: too many arguments
time to sync
```

I am new to bash scripting so thank you in advance.

Comment: Add option `-s` to du command.

Comment: see what's the value of actualsize by printing it. `echo "$actualsize"`

Comment: or do `echo $(du -m "$file")`

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
[: too many arguments
```

seems to indicate that either `$actualsize` or `$minimumsize` is expanding to more than one argument.

Change your script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x                                          # Add this line.
file=private/videos/tv
minimumsize=2
actualsize=$(du -m "$file" | cut -f 1)
echo "[$actualsize] [$minimumsize]"             # Add this line.
if [ $actualsize -ge $minimumsize ]; then
        echo "nothing here to see"
else
        echo "time to sync"
fi
```

The `set -x` will echo commands before attempting to execute them, something which assists *greatly* with debugging.

The `echo "[$actualsize] [$minimumsize]"` will assist in trying to establish whether these variables are badly formatted or not, before the attempted comparison.

If you *do* that, you'll no doubt find that some arguments will result in a lot of output from the `du -m` command since it descends into subdirectories and gives you multiple lines of output.

If you want a *single* line of output for all the subdirectories aggregated, you have to use the `-s` flag as well:

```
actualsize=$(du -ms "$file" | cut -f 1)
```

If instead you don't want any of the subdirectories taken into account, you can take a slightly different approach, limiting the depth to one and tallying up all the sizes:

```
actualsize=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -al | awk '{s += $6} END {print int(s/1024/1024)}')
```

Comment: So I think what is happening is it is getting all of the sizes of each of the sub folders as well and turning them into arguments. Any ideas on how to just target the parent directory and state if that is over 2M then do X